# Trouble inserting into last position in array list

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, insert

I'm trying to insert a word into an alphabetically sorted array of words. the code below converts the array to an arraylist and inserts the word into the right place. However, if the word to be inserted has to go at the very end, it doesn't get inserted. For the last for loop, I tried setting the condition to <= aList.size () but i get an a ArrayList.rangeCheck and ArrayList.get exception. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class insertSort {

public static void main(String args []) {

    String [] sortedArray = new String [] {"aa", "ball", "dog", "zebra", "zzz"};

    ArrayList <String> aList = new ArrayList <String> (); //create new arraylist

    for (int i=0; i < sortedArray.length; i++){
        String temp = sortedArray [i];
        aList.add(temp);
    }

    System.out.println(aList);                     

    String word = "zzzz";
    for (int i =0; i < aList.size();i++) {
        String temp = aList.get(i);
        int comparisonResult = word.compareTo(temp) ;
        if (comparisonResult < 0 | comparisonResult == 0) {
            aList.add(i , word);
            break;}

        }


    System.out.println(aList);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a boolean to record whether you successfully inserted the word ahead of any others, and if not, add it to the end of the array:

```
boolean wasInserted = false;
for (int i =0; i < aList.size();i++) {
    String temp = aList.get(i);
    int comparisonResult = word.compareTo(temp) ;
    if (comparisonResult < 0 || comparisonResult == 0) {
        aList.add(i , word);
        wasInserted = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!wasInserted) {
    aList.add(word);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The for loop will only add the new word to the List if the word comes alphabetically before another word or if it equals another word in your list. In the case of

```
String word = "zzzz";
```

This does come alphabetically before another or equal another word so it is not added.
You need to add some sort of check to see if the work was added and if not, call

```
aList.add(word)
```

to add the new word to the end of the list.